# Installing libgkt-4-dev on Ubuntu 23.10 results in libxfixes3 version mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gtk

I'm trying to learn gtk4 application development, but even after a bunch of various attempts to fix it, `sudo apt install libgtk-4-dev` still returns the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxfixes-dev : Depends: libxfixes3 (= 1:6.0.0-2) but 1:6.0.0-6~ubuntu21.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It's clear that a library version mismatch is going on, but I'm out of ideas on how I'd be able to resolve it. Manually attempting to install libxfixes-dev results in the same error, as does attempting to install with aptitude instead of apt.

So far I've tried:

- Updating my system (`sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`, as well as `sudo apt dist-upgrade`)
- Disabling all the third party PPAs on my system
- Installing the specific version of libxfixes using `sudo apt install --reinstall libxfixes3=1:6.0.0-2`, but cancelled as this would uninstall my entire graphics stack

None of the above seems to have changed anything, I'm still getting the same error message as originally.

This is my first time diving into something that would require the libXYZ-dev packages, so package version managing is a bit out of my depth. How would I go about resolving the conflict?

Comment: Usually this kind of thing is the result of old PPAs in your sources - I'd start by looking at the output of `apt policy libxfixes3 libxfixes-dev`

Comment: @steeldriver I put the output of that to pastebin, looks like there are in fact 2 versions of libxfixes3, though not sure where one of them is coming from https://pastebin.com/9Qdh0qNd

Comment: It looks like you have a version (`6.0.0-6~ubuntu21.10`) that based on the name belongs to the EOL unsupported Kinetic release. Did you remember to run `sudo apt update` before attempting the install?

Comment: Yes, I've run apt update and upgrade before trying to install anything and despite some third party legacy PPAs erroring, all the packages are supposed to be up to date. I'll try to clean out the erroring PPAs and see if that helps in any capacity.

Comment: With all errors when running an apt update gone, I'm still running in the same problem as in the original post

Comment: `sudo apt Install --reinstall libxfixes3=1:6.0.0-2`

Comment: @nobody attempting that results in apt wanting to uninstall most of the GPU driver stack

Comment: Oh `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` also `sudo apt update` please.

Comment: @nobody here https://pastebin.com/e8RvQ8CK

Comment: Sorry I'm out. to much foreign sources with different architecture  and mantic-proposed enabled.

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the attempt at least. I disabled mantic-proposed, as I didn't know I have that enabled, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am running Pop OS and I basically ran into exactly the same issue, except that I had the problem with `libxfixes3=1:6.0.0-1` instead of `libxfixes3=1:6.0.0-2`. So after trying out `sudo apt install --reinstall libxfixes3=1:6.0.0-1`, I also saw some graphics libraries being uninstalled. But upon closer inspection it just mainly seemed to be steam and not my entire graphic stack.

So in the end I ended up doing this and installing my actual required dependency (in my case it was `libsdl2-dev`). After that I just reinstalled steam and after restarting my pc everything seems to work.

Comment: After a closer inspection, it looked like it wants to uninstall the graphics stack for i386 architecture as well as wine in my case. I pulled the trigger, went ahead with the reinstall and afterwards reinstalled wine. Everything seems to work fine now, thanks.